# flutter googlemap zoomcontrol position

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I am using google_maps_flutter package to create a map in app. I am using below function

```
GoogleMap(
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: _locationCoords, zoom: 12.0),
                        markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
                        onMapCreated: mapCreated,
                        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                        scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                        compassEnabled: true,
                      )
```

The problem is with zoom controls. I can see zoom controls appearing but i want to change the position of zoomcontrols to appear on the right side. Is it possible to change the position of zoom controls.

Comment: Looks like there's not yet an option to change the zoom control position in google_maps_flutter package

Answer (score 9):

I didn't find any solution so i created custom zoom controls and using map controller to added them on map.

```
Positioned(
      top: 100,
      left: 5,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 2,
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
          width: 40,
          height: 100,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var currentZoomLevel = await _controller.getZoomLevel();

                    currentZoomLevel = currentZoomLevel + 2;
                    _controller.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                        CameraPosition(
                          target: locationCoords,
                          zoom: currentZoomLevel,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
              SizedBox(height: 2),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var currentZoomLevel = await _controller.getZoomLevel();
                    currentZoomLevel = currentZoomLevel - 2;
                    if (currentZoomLevel < 0) currentZoomLevel = 0;
                    _controller.animateCamera(
                      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                        CameraPosition(
                          target: locationCoords,
                          zoom: currentZoomLevel,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: For more general approach without animating to certain coordinates:  `var currentZoomLevel = await myStore.mapController.getZoomLevel();
currentZoomLevel = currentZoomLevel + 2;
myStore.mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.zoomTo(currentZoomLevel));`

Comment: The current `locationCoords` can be found in `provider.cameraPosition.target`. Very nice solution, because it will also work for iOS which Google isn't even supporting.

Comment: I used that solution ,It was awesome
But I added it to IOS  as special case
Because this part is available in Android   " zoomControlsEnabled:true"

Comment: @MartinBraun what is the provider here? what do I assign provider as?

Comment: @just10minutes I'm maintaining a [fork](https://github.com/martin-braun/google_maps_place_picker_mb/) that will help you. Unfortunately, I wasn't aware that the `PlaceProvider` was an own class in my codebase, really thought it was provided by Google. Make a full-text search for `_buildZoomButtons()` and follow definitions and references to learn how to put this together in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 7):

Try putting padding option in GoogleMap() widget

```
GoogleMap(
               initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
               target: _locationCoords, zoom: 12.0),
               markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
               onMapCreated: mapCreated,
               zoomControlsEnabled: true,
               zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
               scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
               compassEnabled: true,
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                 bottom:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.25),
         )
```

> padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.25),

Comment: May be people will not happy with zoomControlsEnabled: true in iOS devices!